# how to write @token_required function using sqlalchemy core?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pyjwt

I've written a function to get user details of logged in user using uid(uuid) but how to add @token_required functionality for this after user logged in?

As I've seen in most of the resources people have done it using normal sqlalchmey but I've implemented this **using SqlAlchemy core**.

I'm new to this and not getting ahead because I'm not able to resolve this issue. Please help!!

Login code

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST'])
def login():

    auth = user_schema.load(request.get_json())

    user_name = auth['user_name']
    password = auth['password']
    conn = engine.connect()
    results = conn.execute(text("SELECT id, user_name, password, email_address, dob, uid FROM user WHERE (user_name = :user_name)"), {
                           "user_name": user_name})
    # print(results)
    result_dict = [dict(u) for u in results.fetchall()]
    print(result_dict[0])
    data = result_dict[0]
    print("data :", data)
    # return result_dict[0]

    if data['user_name'] != auth['user_name']:
        return make_response('Could not verify user, Please signup!', 401, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic-realm= "No user found!"'})

    if check_password_hash(data['password'], auth['password']):
        token = jwt.encode({'uid': data['uid']},
                           app.config['SECRET_KEY'], 'HS256')
        return make_response(jsonify({'token': token}), 201)

    return make_response('Could not verify password!', 403, {'WWW-Authenticate': 'Basic-realm= "Wrong Password!"'})
```

user_detail route

```
@app.route('/users/<uid>', methods=['GET'])
def profile_view(uid):
    print("user_details")
    conn = engine.connect()
    str_sql = text("""SELECT * FROM user WHERE uid = uid""", {"uid": uid})
    results = conn.execute(str_sql).fetchall()
    print(results)
    return users_scehma.dump(results)
```